# Search for special characters isn't working as advertised

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

According to Stack Overflow's [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) docs:

> To find a specific phrase, or to search a string of special characters, enter it in quotes: like `"flat tire"`, or `"<%#"`.

But searching for [`"<%#"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%3C%25%23%22) doesn't yield *any* results, neither does [`code:"<%#"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3A%22%3C%25%23%22).

This is a [long standing bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249848/search-using-symbols-is-broken) (reported in 2015) and for some reason it is not getting fixed.

I'm therefore asking to **update the help page** accordingly.

Either remove the "special characters" part or provide a working solution. The current help is not helpful at all.

Comment: '*This is a long standing bug (reported in 2015) and for some reason it is not getting fixed.*' - This seems to be the case, more and more. I think the main focus is Teams / Careers.

Answer (score 6):

Yeah... This is misleading. I've wasted time on fruitless effort trying to get it to work before too; apparently this is something we broke in one of the Elastic upgrades, so it'll probably take some work to get it back.

In the meantime, removing the stumbling block from the search help is a good idea. So I've done so, with a comment to remind me to re-add it when this works again.